# How i can change Bottom sheet height dynamically based on a tab bar view in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx, bottom-sheet

i want the height of the bottom sheet to change based on each tab bar view ex. (200 for the first,400 for the second..etc)

here is the current code from the getx controller

```
    adjustViews = [
      whiteBalance(controller, screenHeight),
      Container(
        height: 400,
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
      Container(
        height: 500,
        color: Colors.amber,
      ),
      Container(
        color: Colors.pink,
      ),
      Container(
        height: 200,
        color: Colors.purpleAccent,
      ),
    ];


  Expanded(
                    child: TabBarView(
                        controller: adjusttabController.value,
                        children: adjustViews),
                  )
```

tried expanded, obs heights and nothing worked